# Paginate a One to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I have a Model `Topic` and `Post`.

Each `Topic` has many `Post`.

My `Topic` model extends Eloquent with a one-to-many relationship for `Post`.

```
class Topic extends Eloquent
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

}
```

My `Post` model also extends Eloquent.

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{

    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }

}
```

In my `TopicController`, I would like to paginate my posts through the relationship. I expended something like this would work:

```
$topic->posts->paginate(20);
```

However, it is a `Collection` object. As such, I get the following error message.

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()

**How do I correctly paginate a one-to-many relationship?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `$topic->posts` is different from `$topic->posts()`. While the former is an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object. The latter is an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` object.

Therefore, the following would work.

```
$topic->posts()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: how do you use the render function to print the numbers?

Comment: ok, I find the way ` $topic->posts()->paginate(10)->render() `

Comment: There is a minus of this method, Eager Loading does not work. How to use ->with() ?